# User defined signal 1

Tags: c, linux, unix, ubuntu

I'm developing a client-server program and when I'm trying to send a signal to another process, it just display this sentence "User defined signal 1". As you can see in the code, I am using the `SIGUSR1`.

Client:

```
void Exit(req req)
{
    kill(req.server_pid, SIGUSR1);
    fprintf(stdout,"\n[CLIENT] Closing the client...\n");
    sleep(2);
    unlink(FIFO_CLIENT);
    exit(0);
}
```

Server:

```
void ClientLeft (int sig)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"\n[CLIENT] Just left the game!");
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, ClientLeft);
}
```

I don't understand why the client doesn't run the rest of the lines, and even the server doesn't show the printf.

Comment: `server` and `client` are running on the same system?

Comment: From where does the "User defined signal 1" come? Specifically, are you sure the function "Exit" is actually called?

Comment: @Odexios, this sentence displays in the client console. And i call the function when i want to close the client, and let the server knows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You should read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) ...

You'll understand why your code is against the rules (in principle you should never use [`printf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) or `fprintf` inside a signal handler, see also explanations about [calling Qt functions from Unix signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html)).

Then, you should remember that [stdio(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is buffered. So add a `\n` at *end* of your `printf` format string. Or call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) or [setvbuf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html).

The good habit to have is to always end `printf` format strings with `\n` and if you don't do that, call `fflush(NULL)` at *appropriate* places.

Also, use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on both client and server code to check that `SIGUSR1` signal was indeed sent and handled.

Your `main` function (as you show it on the server side) is too short. The process running your `main` is very probably exiting before having any chance to get any signal. On my computer your "server program" runs in less than a millisecond.

At last, using signals is very probably a bad way to communicate between server and clients. Consider using [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

If you use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.%20org/) compiler, be sure to enable all warnings and debug info, so compile first [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.

Comment: "Exit" should still print its message; if it doesn't, I'd wager it's not actually called; besides, even if `printf` isn't async safe and so it shouldn't be used, it still should work in this simple code without many issues.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, i cut all of the code lines on the main function, and i just left the important. I don't know if it is correct way to post on stack overflow, but i'm a beginner, and i didn't know it unfortunately.

Comment: Then, the wrong format strings might explain something, and please use `strace`

Comment: Using the strace i found out that my client doesn't receive the Server PID properly, trying to send a signal to a PID with value "0".

Comment: Your client need to know the pid of the server. It is an integer >1.